# Laravel File In Directory Loop Doesn't Include 3,4,7,8,9 and 11

Tags: laravel, loops, directory

So a couple of months ago I made this simple image uploader with Laravel, however today I noticed that some of the "recent uploaded" images I am calling with a loop ([RecentImagesController.php](https://github.com/RafaelDeJongh/AP-Images/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/RecentImagesController.php)) through my upload folder, doesn't seem to be shown based on the following numbers:

03,04,07,08,09 and 11

However if I change the folder number to 01,02,05,06,10 or 12 then the content does get shown.

This is the loop that I have currently:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use File;
class RecentImagesController extends Controller{
    public function recentImages(){
        $thumbPath = public_path('up/').date("Y/m").'/thumbs/';
        File::isDirectory($thumbPath) or File::makeDirectory($thumbPath,0775,true,true);
        foreach(array_reverse(File::directories("up")) as $dirYears){
            foreach(File::directories($dirYears) as $dir){
                foreach(array_reverse(File::files($dir)) as $path){
                    $files[] = pathinfo($path);
                }
            }
        }
    return view("recent-images-view")->with("files",$files);
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure to why this works with some numbers, and specifically not with those other numbers, or at least I can't directly spot the pattern into why this is happening.

The application as it is can be found here: https://ap-images.ga/recent
And all the files in the following github repo: https://github.com/RafaelDeJongh/AP-Images

However I think it's purely something to do with the loop (https://github.com/RafaelDeJongh/AP-Images/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/RecentImagesController.php) yet I am not exactly sure to what this problem is.

So to anyone who could help me further with this "problem" I thank you already in advance.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the code in your question. You shouldn't rely on links to external sites for your code. Make sure you include an [mcve] of your code.

Comment: @KirkBeard Ah okay, I thought it would be easier for people to see the code in Github than here directly in the post. But with that said, I've added said loop.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work that way though. Your code in Github may change in the future, rendering this question unhelpful to others who might also run into the issue. There's a [FAQ entry](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) on Meta which discusses the reasons for it.

Comment: @KirkBeard yea that actually makes perfect sense, at the time of writing, didn't really thought of that, and only thought it would be easier for people to see the Github code view rather than the inline code here.

Either way thanks for mentioning that ;)